# Remove border style from a PrimeFaces p:dataScroller

Tags: css, jsf, web-applications, primefaces

I'm trying to remove the border of this dataScroller from PrimeFaces 6.1 however I've tried creating the class below in CSS and applied it to the dataScroller but it does not work.

```
.datascroller{
border-style: none;
border-color: transparent;
}
```

And this is my dataScroller:

```
 <p:dataScroller value="#{dataScrollerView.adotar}" var="anuncio" chunkSize="3" styleClass="datascroller"></p:dataScroller>
```

The border that I refer to is that line of the image of link below.

[Border line in dataScroller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnOJR.png)

Comment: Learn about css specificity

Comment: I'll try this question solution.